How do we define Sheaves in terms of closed set covers?
A JSTOR paper  I can’t access claims to use Topos theory etc to develop sheaves in terms of closed set covers.   Was wanting a general overview of this or some alternative accessible reference.
All that I need is up to the definition of a closed set sheaf.  I don’t even need the theory that comes afterward, at the moment.
I’ve tried in my application to cover open sets by these closed sets and vise versa, but it’s not working out.  I have a function defined on finite integer intervals and there is much overlap, but I can also express the piecewise function in terms of disjoint, finite and closed sets.  This allows covering of each interval with open sets which are pairwise disjoint also by a theorem of Urysohn.  However; I can’t do it for finite number of closed pieces for various reasons which would normally allow pasting lemma to apply.  And I can’t cover infinitely many closed intervals covering my domain space with disjoint open sets, because then Urysohn’s lemma doesn’t apply.
So I’m hoping that if I had a short list of bullets / links / vocab to google; then I could perhaps  recreate the definition of closed set sheaf from scratch on my own.  I just don’t know where to begin.  E.g. should I know more about Grothendieck topology?
My background is I know how to prove some basic things in elementary toposes.

More about my background.  Here are some elementary Topos proof examples and I also have some on MSE from Johnstone.   https://enjoysmath.blogspot.com/search?updated-max=2022-01-07T05:09:00-08:00&max-results=7&start=7&by-date=false&m=1

Also found this: https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-94-015-8453-1_12  where they said closed set sheaves were even developed before open set sheaves, so why so little about them?

Yes, you should go learn about sheaves with respect to Grothendieck topology. The reason why sheaves with respect to closed covers are not much discussed is probably simply that arbitrary unions of closed subsets need not be closed. Also the construction of espaces étalés does not work.

Let $X$ be a topological space.
A closed set presheaf on $X$ in the sense of the cited article is a presheaf on the poset of closed subsets of $X$, i.e. a contravariant functor from the poset of closed subsets of $X$ to the category of sets.
Since the poset of closed subsets of $X$ is isomorphic to the opposite of the poset of open subsets of $X$, this is the same thing as a copresheaf on the poset of open subsets of $X$, i.e. a covariant functor from the poset of open subsets of $X$ to the category of sets, but since cosheaves are defined by a completely different condition, it is best to not confuse closed set presheaves and copresheaves.
A closed set sheaf on $X$ is a closed set presheaf that satisfies the gluing condition on finite closed covers.
The cited article assumes that closed subsets of $X$ are finite (and therefore that $X$ itself is finite), but the Grothendieck machinery works fine without such an assumption.
We could also define closed set sheaves in terms of possibly infinite closed covers but this is harder to work with.
It is fun to invent definitions, but it is better to have examples.
First, let $Y$ be any set.
Clearly, we have a closed set sheaf on $X$ of all $Y$-valued functions: there is no continuity condition to worry about.
But what if $Y$ is a topological space and we want to restrict to continuous functions?
We certainly have a closed set presheaf of continuous $Y$-valued functions, since the restriction of a continuous function is continuous, and since is a sub-presheaf of the closed set sheaf of all $Y$-valued functions.
Thus, to show that we have a closed set sheaf of continuous $Y$-valued functions, it is enough to show that the result of gluing continuous $Y$-valued functions – which we already know to be a well-defined $Y$-valued function – is also continuous.
Suppose we have a function $f : X \to Y$ and closed subsets $X_\alpha \subseteq X$ such that $X = \bigcup_\alpha X_\alpha$ and the restrictions $f_\alpha : X_\alpha \to Y$ are all continuous.
To show $f$ is continuous, we must show that for every closed subset $Y' \subseteq Y$, $f^{-1} (Y') \subseteq X$ is also closed.
Well,
$$f^{-1} (Y') = \bigcup_\alpha (f^{-1} (Y') \cap X_\alpha) = \bigcup_\alpha f_\alpha^{-1} (Y')$$
and each $f_\alpha^{-1} (Y') \subseteq X_\alpha$ is closed because $f_\alpha$ is continuous.
Closed subsets of $X_\alpha$ are also closed subsets of $X$, so $f^{-1} (Y')$ is a union of closed subsets of $X$.
Now, we finally have to use the finiteness condition in the definition of closed set sheaf: we only care about finite covers, so $f^{-1} (Y')$ is a union of finitely many closed subsets of $X$, hence is closed.
Therefore $f$ is continuous.
Finally, let me remark that the category of closed set sheaves on $X$ is actually equivalent to the category of (open set) sheaves on a certain compact space $\hat{X}$ related to $X$.
This is easy to see in the case where $X$ is finite: in that case, a collection of subsets is a closed set topology on $X$ if and only if it is an open set topology on $X$, so $\hat{X}$ can be taken to be $X$ retopologised with the definition of open and closed interchanged.

In my app the function $\pi_2$ definitely not continuous in Furstenberg topology.   We would have noticed a pattern.

Though the twin prime pair counter is the pointwise limit of uniformly continuous functions on NN which restricted to U_I form the sections.   It sucks but continuity of the global section is hopeless.  Do you know if Sheaf theory could measure how discontinuous it is?
